# Python: get new list from some contents of tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples, python-3.5

I have a tuple `x`.

```
x = (('PHACTR', 5),
 ('DPEP', 6),
 ('FREM', 7),
 ('ODAM', 5),
 ('PCP', 8),
 ('DYNC', 5),
 ('ZNRF', 8),
 ('WIF', 4))
```

I don't know how to use `list.append` or `list.extend` methods in this case.

How can I get a list containing `['PHACTR, DPEP, FREM, ODAM, PCP, DYNC,ZNRF, WIF']`?

Comment: May I ask why you want a list with one element instead of a string?

Comment: @timgeb Actually, the OP says they want a list containing `['PHACTR, DPEP, FREM, ODAM, PCP, DYNC,ZNRF, WIF']`; that would be a one element list containing a list containing a single string, i.e.,  `alist = [['PHACTR, DPEP, FREM, ODAM, PCP, DYNC,ZNRF, WIF']]` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to end with one string in a list:

```
out = [', '.join([t[0] for t in x])]
```

Comment: Or in Python 3.6: `[', '.join([*zip(*x)][0])]`, in Python 2: `[', '.join(zip(*x)[0])]` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over your tuple (which contains tuples) and take the first element using list comprehension:

```
[t[0] for t in x]
```

This returns a list with the names.

edit: if you want a list containing a string with commas you should use Roelants answer. I misread the question.

Comment: ['PHACTR', 'DPEP', 'FREM', 'ODAM', 'PCP', 'DYNC', 'ZNRF', 'WIF']


I want to have comma only between t[0]s inside my list, like PHACTR, DPEP, FREM

Comment: So you want to end with one string? If I understand you right? See my answer :)